# Blender crashed. Reopened project. Now my textures aren't loaded. Completely new to this

Tags: texturing

Why can't I apply the picture to the object? I spent six hours working on textures, and made sure to save every 5 minutes. When blender crashed I thought, oh well let me just reboot. But when I get in I can see the texture I worked on in the thumbnail but it just shows grey on material preview.

[image]

Comment: So now I'm seeing that I'm supposed to save the image seperately or pack it into the file? I want to cry. I spent all day on this and had such a beautiful texture. Blender is an amazing piece of software but this is such a massive oversight. How utterly disappointing.

Comment: What I don't understand is why the texture I made is still present in the thumbnail? I can see it right there at character2_body. If there's any chance I can recover this please let me know.

Comment: how did you save your texture, did you Save As or did you pack? Hard to know what happened, can you open them in the Image Editor or UV Editor? Maybe you've lost them...

Comment: I'm sorry I have to say that, but if you worked on the texture without ever manually saving it, it's lost. This is frustrating and there are discussions about Blender developers not fixing it, like this one starting August 2015(!) for example: https://projects.blender.org/blender/blender/issues/45636 but so far, nothing has changed. And you can read there about other dangerous ways to lose your texture even if Blender does not crash...